# How to add order summary to checkout success page?

Tags: checkout, orders

I have been looking into adding an order summary on the checkout success page in Magento but I can't seem to find any information on how to do this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or show me how I could implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to try echoing this variable:

> 'Amount Paid:' . Mage::helper("core")->currency($order_details->total_paid)

In the page that you want to.

Comment: if that gave you the answer, mark it as solved please.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet

Comment: ok, once you do let me know.

Comment: The code above seemed to work but I needed to have the full order details so used the code here https://www.alphachannelgroup.com/custom-magento-order-confirmation/ as a guide.

Comment: ok,but if the above code helped you please mark the question as solved.